# generating documentation for large IT system

Tags: documentation, data-modeling

i have complicated IT system with no usefull documentation, developed over 15 year by countless number of devs with different experiance
i am not a DBA, just last line of support - so my task is to know how things works, and keep it working  (mix of technical and functional guy)

i am working on it for about 4 months and i have to start making my own documentation as i am forgetting things that i found about the system on my own

i have acces to the application and DB , no source code , i can run sql monitor so i know what queries are run on the db

db have no internal constraint (no forein keys no nothing)
db consist of several not connected data models (my guess is 3-4)

i have two things to document

one is functional , what app does
one is data model , how it is implemented , how data model works

later on i would like to map one to another

i have no idea how to tackle this problem

i dont want to create fully functional documentation that would describe every aspect of the app

i just want to create some diagrams, models  that i could modyfi along the way as i get to know the system as i want to avoid situation when i am resolving problems that i ve already solved

mayby i am to young and after another 6 months i will give up as everyone else
nonetheless i want to try :D

any ideas how to start documenting it , any software to document gui and link it to data model ?

Comment: Step 1 - start fixing the database by adding foreign keys based on how the joins in existing queries look (unless there are no such connections, which would be a extremely strange / badly designed database, well, no foreign keys is already pretty badly designed).

Comment: How are you expected to keep an application working if you don't have access to the source? Does anyone maintain the source? As time passes, it's entirely probable that an app will start getting used differently and bugs are discovered.

Comment: i have been working on several big DBs(500GB+) and none of them had constraints, thats how real world looks when you get out of CS class -
crappy snippets of bash and sql codes glued together with tons of money  and guys with sleep deprivation, i dont have access to the code - its politycs, some manager decided it would be cheper to pay me insted of paying for source code (we are the users, its not in house development)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download MYSQL Workbench to create the entity–relationship model. It looks like I wrote this because I am in the same exact situation as you.